# How to return email to top of inbox using Google Apps Script

Tags: api, email, google-apps-script, gmail

I am attempting to make my own version of Boomerang, a script that returns emails to your inbox at a later time as specified by the user.

I am using Google Apps Script and I have everything working except I can't return the email to the top of the inbox. I've tried forwarding the email with the relevant script, but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

---

Here's a few examples of the code I've tried (none of which produce the result I'm looking for):

### Test 1:

```js
  messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
      messages[i][0].reply("<b>This message has been moved to the top of your inbox per your request. Please take action soon.</b>", {
        replyTo: "desiredEmail@gmail.com"
      });
  }
```

### Test 2:

```js
  messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
      forward("desiredEmail@gmail.com", {
         htmlBody: "<b>This message has been moved to the top of your inbox per your request. Please take action soon.</b>",
         name: "ServAce85",
         replyTo: "desiredEmail@gmail.com",
         from: "desiredEmail@gmail.com",
         subject: "Re: " + messages[i].getSubject()

      });
   }
```

### Test 3:

```js
  messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {          
       messages[i][0].forward("desiredEmail@gmail.com", {
         subject: messages[i][0].getSubject()
       });
  }
```

### Test 4:

```js
function moveEmail(threadsToMove) {
  var  threads = threadsToMove;
  var  messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
    messages[i][0].forward(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), {
        subject: "Re: " + messages[i][0].getSubject(),
          htmlBody: "<b>This message has been moved to the top of your inbox per your request. Please take action soon.</b></n>" + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + "</n>" + messages[i][0].getBody()
      });
    GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), "Re: " + messages[i][0].getSubject(), messages[i][0].getPermalink());
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```js
function moveEmail() {
  var  threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 2); // Change to what you want the threads to be
  var  messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
      messages[i][0].forward("CHANGEEMAIL@GMAIL.COM", {
          htmlBody: "<b>This message has been moved to the top of your inbox per your request. Please take action soon.</b></n>" + messages[i][0].getBody()
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: This moves the message to the top of the inbox simply by forwarding it, but it doesn't create a new message in that thread and move the entire thread to the top. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I came here to look for a solution on something similar as Pause inbox.

Made this of it:

1) Make a filter in Gmail so every new mail bypasses the inbox and gets labeled as a custom label you created.

2) Make timetriggers for following google script function:

```
function moveTheMails(){
  var label0 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Custom Label/Sublabel if wanted");
  var threads = label0.getThreads();
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].moveToInbox();
    threads[i].removeLabel(label0);
  }
}
```

Voila, dependend on your timetriggers your new mails get delivered to your inbox at the custom times.
As gmail-filter I used:
from:(-{a@b.com OR c@d.com}) to:(me1@my.com OR me2@my.com)
The adresses in from are excluded (-) in the filter so mails from that persons are directly delivered in the inbox.